# How do I "AND" across a range of cells in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Given that I have a range of cells (say A1:F1), in which all those cells contain either TRUE or FALSE. I know that I can write the formula `=AND(A1:F1)` in G1 which will "AND" across that range and return either TRUE or FALSE to G1.

My question is how would I do the something in VBA? Everything I find leads me to believe that I have to write code that looks something like

```vb
If A1 And B1 And C1 And D1 And E1 And F1 Then ...
```

But there must be a better way.

I've tried `Var = And(A1:F1)` and `Var = Application.WorksheetFunction.And(A1:F1)` both result in a line of red code.

I sure it's simple but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: `Var = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("And(A1:F1)")`

Comment: `Var = Application.WorksheetFunction.And(Range("A1:F1"))`

Comment: The uncompilable code is because VBA has no idea what `A1:F1` means, since that's Excel syntax, not VBA. I'd go with @GSerg's early-bound solution (with the `Range` member call ideally qualified with a proper `Worksheet` object), over Scott's late-bound one, but both should work fine.

Comment: Small edition on @ScottCraner one, `Var = Sheet1.[AND(A1:F1)]` ... essentially the same thing

Comment: Thank you all. These answers have been very helpful